# Independence and Conditional Probability Confusion

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, naive-bayes

I am trying to understand the derrivations associated with the Naive Bayes assumption. One document I read starts off by stating this:

> \begin{align}
> P(x | C_k) &= P(x_1, x_2, \dots , x_D |C_k) \\
>  & = P(x_1 | x_2, \dots, x_D,C_k) P(x_2 | x_3, \dots, x_D,C_k) \dots P(x_{D−1} | x_D,C_k) P(x_D |C_k)
> \end{align}
>   We can simplify things if we naively assume that the individual feature dimensions $(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_D)$
>   are independent, that is:
>   $P(x_1 | x_2, x_3, \dots, x_D, C_k) = P(x_1 | C_k) $

I don't understand how the last equality in the quote is derived. I tried reverting back to the basic definition of conditional probability (ie. $P(A | B) = \frac{P(A, B)}{ P(B)}$, but for some reason could not prove that left side equals right side.

Can somebody please provide the steps for derriving the last line (ie. providing the left = right side) ?

Comment: Before the last line they assume that the individual feature dimensions are independent, that is $P(x_i| x_j) = P(x_i)$ for all $i, j  = \{1,2, \dots, D\}$ and $i \neq j$. Using this you can simplify all the terms to the required expression.

Comment: When expanding the left I get \begin{align} P(x1, x2, x3, ...Ck ) /  P(x2, x3, ...Ck ) =  [ P(x1, Ck) P(x2, Ck) P(x3, Ck) ... P(xD, Ck) ] / [ P(x2, Ck) P(x3, Ck) ... P(xD, Ck) ] =  P(x1, Ck) \end{align} whereas the left side is $ P(x1, Ck) / P(Ck) $. What am I doing wrong in this step ?

Answer (score 1):

Using a slight change in notation, the simplest version of the identity is
$$ P(x,y\mid C)=P(x\mid y, C)P(y\mid C)\tag1
$$
which you can prove as follows:
$$
P(x,y\mid C)=\frac{P(x,y,C)}{P(C)}=\frac{P(x,y,C)}{P(y,C)}\frac{P(y,C)}{P(C)}
=P(x\mid y, C)P(y\mid C)
$$
You can prove further iterations of this identity by applying (1) repeatedly.
For example, the three-variable version proceeds as follows:
$$
P(x,\color{red}{y,z}\mid C)=P(x \mid \color{red}{y,z},C)P(\color{red}{y,z}\mid C)\tag2
$$
by replacing  $y$ in (1) with the pair $\color{red}{y,z}$. Then expand the second factor on the RHS of (2):
$$
P(x,y,z\mid C)=P(x \mid y,z,C)\color{red}{P(y,z\mid C)} = P(x \mid y,z,C)\color{red}{P(y\mid z, C)P(z\mid C)}
$$
by replacing $x,y$ in (1) with $y,z$ respectively. See if you can prove the four-variable version:
$$
P(x,y,z,w\mid C)=P(x\mid y,z,w,C)P(y\mid z,w,C)P(z\mid w,C)P(w\mid C)
$$